# javascript fontsize() less than 1

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

I have a quick question.
is it possible to set font size of variable to less than 1? I know that fontsize() function accepts only integers between 1 and 7 but I need little bit less. Is it possible with other function, or is there any other solution please?

Comment: Why are you using [`fontsize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fontsize) instead of a `span` with css? `fontsize` returns a string with the [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) element, which is deprecated.
@Teemu: [Incorrect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fontsize).

Comment: @Cerbrus Looks like I've missed something, thanks.

Comment: I am  trying to do something like this: $('#dod').html(cenaEl+' EUR'+bezdph); I dont want to split it into two divs or spans because it will bring in a lot of code (i have more of such lines and that way for each line there would be 2 divs)